# mongodb find where field lower than another field plus parameter value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following collection in mongodb, lets call it "products":

```
[
  {
    "name"           : "Product X",
    "warehouseStock" : 50,
    "reservedStock"  : 41
  },
  {
    "name"           : "Product Y",
    "warehouseStock" : 50,
    "reservedStock"  : 10
  }
]
```

I want to have a find() query that returns the documents in this collection where 'warehouseStock' is less than ('reservedStock' + threshold), where threshold is a parameter passed into the find() query.

I am trying to do the following find() query in node:

```
var threshold = 10;
mongo.getDb().collection('products').find({warehouseStock: {$lt:(threshold+'$reservedStock')}})
```

but this does not seem to work. I know I can do the following:

```
mongo.getDb().collection('products').find({warehouseStock: {$lt:threshold}})
```

but how can I query where

```
warehouseStock < (reservedStock + threshold)
```

So, if threshold was to be =10, then I would only get the first of the two items in the collection example above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) :

```
var threshold = 10;
mongo.getDb().collection('products').find({
    "$where": "this.warehouseStock < (this.reservedStock + " + threshold + ")"
}).toArray(function(err, items) {
    console.log(items);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried $where as well, but I did not have it surrounded by quotes. Again, thank you very much!